# Multiple table - osticket

Tags: mysql, server, webserver, osticket

My query gives multiple row per ticket. I want to list all custom values in one row. I want the `val.value` listed as columns against each `ticket_id` when I query my database, instead of multiple row for each `ticket_id`

I want the output to show the `val.value` as columns instead.

```
SELECT 
ticket.ticket_id,ticket.`number`,ticket.dept_id,val.field_id,val.value,
ticket.staff_id,ticket.team_id,user.name,   dept.dept_name,status.state,status.name as 
status,ticket.source,ticket.isoverdue,ticket.isanswered,ticket.created 
FROM ost_TICKET ticket 
LEFT JOIN ost_ticket_status status ON status.id = ticket.status_id 
LEFT JOIN ost_user user ON user.id = ticket.user_id 
LEFT JOIN ost_department dept ON ticket.dept_id=dept.dept_id 
LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry entry ON ticket.ticket_id = entry.object_id 
LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry_values val ON entry.id = val.entry_id
```

Output is as follows:

> ticket_id,number,dept_id,field_id,value,staff_id,team_id,name,dept_name,state,status,source,isoverdue,isanswered,created
>
> 4, 587202,4,3,NULL,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,4,NULL,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,87,NULL,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,117,NULL,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,20,Fish Farm,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,22,Normal,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,73,nya-08-211,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,74,88,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,84,Bara,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,85,Shaba,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,86,Kolkata,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09
> 4,  587202,4,165,Tango,15,0,Mark D,SalesDep,open,Open,Phone,0,0,10/14/2014 9:09

Comment: I think you need to at least show us the schema or sample data.  I have a hunch about what you want, but because you left out critical information, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess (since OP not provided tables schema):

If inside one of the tables that you `JOIN` there are several rows for 1 ticket row you will have double rows for a ticket (for example 2 emails).

Also the query has wrong join:

```
LEFT JOIN ost_email email ON user.id = email.email_id
```

I suppose it should be:

```
LEFT JOIN ost_email email ON user.id = email.user_id
```

**EDIT:**
You can try to use `DISTINCT` but you must check if data in the result is ok.

Comment: thank you for your response. i have included the data extracted. instead of listing as rows, i want to have the data listed by columns. the ticket_id is unique. the field_id and values are all from the form_entry_values table

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
SELECT t.ticket_id,t.number,t.dept_id,v.field_id,v.value,t.staff_id,t.team_id,u.name,d.name,s.state,s.name status,t.source,t.isoverdue,t.isanswered,t.created FROM ost_ticket t,ost_department d,ost_ticket_status s,ost_user u,ost_form_entry e,ost_form_entry_values v where s.id = t.status_id and u.id = t.user_id and t.dept_id=d.id and t.ticket_id = e.object_id and e.id = v.entry_id
```

Comment: And you are getting multiple rows because you selected the value table that is the 1:n relation table (ticket:value)

Comment: By using this you can get the required result I think                                          SELECT t.ticket_id,t.number,t.dept_id,v.field_id,v.value,t.staff_id,t.team_id,u.name,d.name,s.state,s.name status,t.source,t.isoverdue,t.isanswered,t.created FROM ttshd_ticket t,ttshd_department d,ttshd_ticket_status s,ttshd_user u,ttshd_form_entry e,ttshd_form_entry_values v where s.id = t.status_id and u.id = t.user_id and t.dept_id=d.id and t.ticket_id = e.object_id and e.id = v.entry_id group by t.ticket_id